# should we contact a lawyer if we have non stop issues and warrenty repairs in a new home for the last 4 years?

Tags: real-estate, property, consumer-protection

We have been in a new build home for for years and have non stop issues.  we have had everything in the home worked on more than once, in some cases they are still doing repairs.  we have had to deal with non stop issues and BS from Richmond and their representatives for the poor work originally completed and for the work redone during the warranty repairs.  we now have to have all the tile in the home removed and replaced due to grout issues.  at the same time they will also have to redo the master bathroom and casita bathroom tile in the shower area for the same problem.  this is now the 5 or 6 time that they have tried to fix or attempt to resolve the issue. this is for arizona.

Comment: How is this a constitutional law issue?

Comment: You are probably seeking a lawyer too late. Do so ASAP.

Comment: How is that even a question. Go find a lawyer, you are at least 3 years late.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to hire a lawyer and file a lawsuit, but it doesn't sound like you have much of a case unless they broke the terms of a contract. If they have repaired it 5-6 times it is clear they are trying to make good and not reneging on the contract.

Comment: so there is no lemon laws that apply to construction work?

Comment: I don't know where you are so I couldn't say what the laws are there.